# ACSL contract for strstr

Tags: c, string, strstr, frama-c

I'm trying to write a specification for a C function that searches the first occurrence of a string in another string (practically the strstr function of string.h).

The first problem i encountered is that i can't prove loop invariants and i think that there's something wrong in the way i use strlen (axiomatic defined in __fc_string_axiomatic.h)

```
#include<string.h>
/*@ 
    requires valid_string(s1);
    requires valid_string(s2);

*/
char *strfind (const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  if (*s2 == 0) 
      return s1;
  /*@ 
    loop invariant 0 <= s1 - \at(s1,Pre) <= strlen(\at(s1,Pre));
  */
  while (*s1) { 
    const char *rs1 = s1;
    const char *rs2 = s2;
    /*@ 
        loop invariant 0 <= rs1 - s1 <= strlen(s1);
        loop invariant 0 <= rs2 - s2 <= strlen(s2);
    */
    while (*rs1 && *rs2 && (*rs1 == *rs2)) { 
        rs1++; 
        rs2++; 
    }
    if (*rs2 == 0) 
        return s1;
    s1++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Code simplification: `while ((*rs1 == *rs2) && *rs1) {`.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop invariants are correct (I succeeded in proving them), but they are too weak, and you should strengthen them. Here is a version of the function I proved with the [WP](http://frama-c.com/wp.html) plugin of Frama-C, the successor of Jessie.

```
/*@ 
    requires valid_string(s1);
    requires valid_string(s2);
*/
char *strfind (const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  if (*s2 == 0) 
      return s1;
  /*@ 
    loop invariant valid_string(s1);
    loop invariant strlen(\at(s1,Pre)) == (s1 - \at(s1,Pre)) + strlen(s1);
    loop invariant 0 <= s1 - \at(s1,Pre) <= strlen(\at(s1,Pre));
    loop assigns s1;
  */
  while (*s1) { 
    const char *rs1 = s1;
    const char *rs2 = s2;
    /*@ 
        loop invariant valid_string(rs1);
        loop invariant valid_string(rs2);
        loop invariant strlen(\at(s1,Pre)) == (rs1 - \at(s1,Pre)) + strlen(rs1);
        loop invariant strlen(s2) == (rs2 - s2) + strlen(rs2);
        loop invariant 0 <= rs1 - s1 <= strlen(s1);
        loop invariant 0 <= rs2 - s2 <= strlen(s2);
        loop assigns rs1, rs2;
    */
    while (*rs1 && *rs2 && (*rs1 == *rs2)) { 
        rs1++; 
        rs2++; 
    }
    if (*rs2 == 0) 
        return s1;
    s1++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

First, notice that the added loop invariants on `valid_string`. Without them, it is not clear for the provers that `strlen(s1/rs1/rs2)` are still positive, because the pointers may have been increased after the end of the string.

Next, I added equalities relating e.g. `\at(s1,Pre)`, `s1`, and their respective lengths. Those are stronger than the right part of your inequalities, and are used to prove said inequalities -- using the hypothesis `valid_string(s1)`, which ensures that `strlen(s1)>=0`.

The left part of your inequalities are proper loop invariants, and could be proven initially (without any of the extra invariants).

Remember that, for all K, the first K loop invariants must be *inductive*. This means that, under the hypothesis that they hold at iteration `i`, you should be able to prove that they hold at iteration `i+1`. Thus, you may need to write stronger invariants than those you want to prove (as those may not be inductive).

Comment: Thank you! If i wanted to specify two **behaviors** (found/not found) can i simply check (in the **assumes**  clause)  if during execution !*s1 (i.e. main loop reached the end because the pattern hasn't been found)?

Comment: No. `assumes` clauses are evaluated in the pre-state of the function, and cannot refer to what happens inside its body. You will have to use an existential quantification for the success case, and a forall/exists for the failure case.

Comment: To complete byako's comment (but if you have specific issues with behaviors, you should open another question), if you have behaviors, you can use the `for bhv: assert ...; `  to indicate that an assertion should hold only when `bhv` is active. In your case, `for found: assert \false` after the main loop would indicate that when in behavior `found` (that must be precised with an assumes clause on the **pre**-state as indicated), the function should not reach `return 0;`